# Weird error when using 'node-htmlparser' module

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-parsing

I'm reading a behemoth of an XML file, line by line. Using [htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser) (v1.7.3), I'm trying to get the values of the attributes that will eventually be written to database.

Here's the code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sys = require('util');
var htmlparser = require('htmlparser');

function parseFoo(fileName) {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
  var buffer = "";

  stream.addListener('data', function(data) {
    buffer += data.toString();
    var parts = buffer.split('\n');
    parts.forEach(function(part, i) {
      record.buildRecord(part);
    })
    buffer = parts.pop(); // Add remaining text to the buffer.
  })
}

var record = (function() {
  var handler = new htmlparser.DefaultHandler(function (error, dom) {});
  var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);
  return {
    'buildRecord': function(xml) {
      parser.parseComplete(xml);      

      // Only for testing.
      console.error(sys.inspect(handler.dom[0]['children'][0], false, null));
    }
  };
})();

parseFoo('foo.xml');
```

'foo.xml' (UTF-8 encoded) is trivial, it consists of gazillion of lines like this:

```
<w a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4">x</w>
```

When the program reaches a certain line (1204), I get an error:

```
D:\Geci\foo.js:25
    console.error(sys.inspect(handler.dom[0]['children'][0], false, null));

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.buildRecord (D:\Geci\foo.js:26:59)
    at D:\Geci\foo.js:14:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (D:\Geci\foo.js:13:11)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:67:17)
    at [object Object]._emitData (fs.js:1149:10)
    at afterRead (fs.js:1131:10)
    at Object.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:254:17)
```

I'm running this with Windows version of node.js (0.6.5.1).

Is it a bug in htmlparser or is it just me being a node.js newbie?

**EDIT: this bug was solved by adding 'end' listener to `stream` where I take special care of the last line. Plus moving `parts.pop()` before the loop.**

Comment: Well it means that the object "handler" references does not have a property called "dom".

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: the program works for 1203 lines of `<w a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4">x</w>` but fails when I add 1204th line.

Comment: Right, well perhaps you could add more debugging before you assume that "handler" has a "dom" property.  And what exactly is on that line in your XML file?

Comment: Just another `<w a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4">x</w>`. ;) It's different in reality, of course. However, it fails in both cases.

Comment: Added some debug info, thanks for suggestion, Pointy.

Comment: Well that sure looks like some sort of parser problem. The only other thing I'd check for would be to make sure there's not some sort of funny character code buried in the file. (I say that because if I were a parser maintainer I'd probably ask that question :-)

Comment: @geca use https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom instead

Comment: Solved it (see above). There was a problem with handling of the last line.